# Excel can this be automated

Tags: excel

I have to do something manual for now but even that is not working.

I have several datetime columns which comes from an Access export, for patients time in, acknowledged time, Dr. close etc.
and want to show the time only.

For the column which has this data - 1/0/1900 10:30:00 AM when I format
custom and
 `[$-409]h:mm:ss AM/PM` it displays only the time.

But other columns that are more datetime populated like 2017-03-07 `09:54:09.510 -05:00`

i can not get any way to show only the time. SO I had to do all manually. Some days there can be 400 like this, there has to be some way
to automate this.

Comment: So what would you want the cell to say after it's changed? Just `09:54:09.510 -05:00`? Would the other example just say 10:30:00 AM?

Comment: yes with the seconds if we can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not too proficient with cell formats or date manipulation, but a Band-Aid type of solution could be a formula like this that you drag down in an adjacent column to all your dates:

`=IF(LEN(A1) > 28, RIGHT(A1, 18), RIGHT(A1, 11))`

Example:

[image: Example]